# A way to provide arguments for programs called in bash

Tags: c++, bash, exe

I'm trying to run a .exe from c++ using system. The argument, a text file, is asked for after calling the .exe. I need a way to provide this argument.

To clarify in bash I can do this:

```
cd /programlocation
wine program.exe
```

This then outputs,

```
Enter input file name :
```

If i now type

```
inputfile.txt
```

It works, but I cannot figure a way to combine this last step so I can run it using system from c++.

ie. This doesn't work:

```
std::string location = "cd /location/"
std::string program = "wine program.exe"
std::string input = "inputfile.txt";
std::string command = location+"&&"+program+"&&"+input;
const char *cmd = command.c_str();
system(cmd);
```

This just asks for input file in the console.

If you can access it the program I'm trying to run is the a8711v30 esdu aircraft engine noise prediction file.

Comment: Do you want to pass an argument to the EXE or just push some data to the STDIN of the spawned process?

Comment: Push some data to the STDIN of the spawned process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*if* program.exe is reading from stdin and not from the terminal, then you might be able to call system with the string:

```
cd /programlocation && echo inputfile.txt | wine program.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

`"inputfile.txt"` goes into the standard input of `wine program.exe`; it's not a command Bash can understand.

To pipe to/from an external program, you can manually [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) with [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe)s, or use [popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) which would be closer to your current use of [system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system).

```
FILE *cmd_stdin = popen(command.c_str(), "w");
fprintf(cmd_stdin, input);
fclose(cmd_stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep: Using system(3) will work, well enough, most of the time. (It's probably what I'd do too if I was in get-'er-done mode.)

The system(3) library function will pass the string argument to /bin/sh for interpretation on most operating systems.  On Linux and Unix, it'll work... see your man page.  Historically, people shied away from system() on the grounds that one couldn't always make assumptions about the command processor available.  Probably not that much of a worry these days.

The strategy that ephemient sketches out will be more portable, so might be preferable if you're going to run the code in places where you can't be sure what you're going to get with /bin/sh.  In this approach, your code takes over the job of handling the forking and piping that /bin/sh packages so conveniently.

Comment: POSIX specifies that `popen` uses `sh -c '...'` just like `system` does.